# Combining sinusoidal waveforms

Tags: math, physics

Please can someone assist me with how to work this out?
I know the answers as this is a practice question, but not sure how to get there.

Two AC waveforms are described by the expressions:
V1 = 190 sin(2800πt)V
V2 = 10 sin(2800πt − π5)V
If V3 is the resultant combination of these waveforms find the following. Express angles as a decimal using a minus sign if appropriate:

a)  The expression that describes V3 using 2 decimal places.
V3 = sin(2800πt+     )V

Comment: how aer you combining?  addition, subtraction, multiplication, division ...

Comment: It's the same frequency so use phasor notation. It's as if they just gave you a schematic with two AC sources in series. But they gave you it in word and equation form.

Comment: Thank you both. Phasor notation is something I am currently looking at (I'm not an electrical engineer).             Is there anything you'd recommend @DKNguyen that shows worked examples ?

Comment: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/complex-numbers.html

Comment: https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/BackGround/phasor/phasor.html

Comment: Just remember the sinusoid needs to be same frequency because the assumption is that each phasor arrows representing each sinusoid rotates around the unit circle at the same rate so maintain fixed relative angles between each other.

Comment: Thanks DKN - very much appreciated.                                     I tried working through this the other day but not sure how to apply it to combine waveforms. If my understanding is correct both waveforms have the same magnitude with V2 lagging behind by pi5 - which I'm guessing can be converted to radians?

Comment: @StarlingArrow Yes, but the sine argument is already in radians. Rewrite/convert in polar, cartesian or exponential form as required to do your desired operation. Addtion/subtraction and multiplication/division are simpler in some forms than others. Otherwise you need trig identities to mash the two sine equations together.

Comment: \$5\pi =180^o\$

Comment: @DKNguyen ok, I've found out how to work this through using phasor analytical method. There is an error in the above equation equation in that it should be π/5.

Comment: @StarlingArrow Double check your interpretation of everything is correct. Adding to x argument in an causes things happen earlier (moves the graph to the left on the x axis, or decreases the phase shift angle). So
Acos(ωt−θ)
would be written as
A∠θ. Also, remember it is in terms of cosine, not sine because at zero phase cosine is 1 and all real (all x-axis) on the unit circle

Answer (score 1):

Well, writing them into complex notation gives (and assuming that combining the two voltages mean: adding them):

$$\underline{\text{V}}=190\exp\left(0\cdot\text{j}\right)+10\exp\left(-5\pi\text{j}\right)=190+10\cos\left(5\pi\right)-10\sin\left(5\pi\right)\text{j}=$$
$$190+10\left(-1\right)-10\left(0\right)\text{j}=180\tag1$$

So, we get:

$$\left|\underline{\text{V}}\right|=180\tag2$$

And:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}\right)=0\tag3$$

So:

$$\text{V}\left(t\right)=180\sin\left(2800\pi t\right)\tag4$$

Comment: I believe that answer to be in correct but thanks for the attempt